# Why doesn't $(this) work inside a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've attached an onlick event to a function. I want to reference the element being clicked from inside the function so I can change its inner HTML, but why is it not working? Is there any other way to reference the clicked element?

**HTML**

```
        <div class="save_button" onclick="toggle_save_star(<?php echo $listing->listing_id ?>,'<?php echo base_url()?>')">
            <?php if($listing->saved_element_id):?>
            <img src="<?php echo site_url('images/core/icons/basic2/star1_16.png')?>" />
            <?php else:?>
            <img src="<?php echo site_url('images/core/icons/basic2/star1_16_gray.png')?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

**Javascript Function**

```
function toggle_save_star(element_id, site_url) {
    var url = site_url+"AJAX/ajax_default/modify_saved";
    var button = $(this);
    $.post(url,{action: 'toggle', element_id: element_id, type: 'listing' }, function(data) {
        if(data == 'saved') {
            $(button).html('<img src="'+site_url+'images/core/icons/basic2/star1_16.png" />');
        }
        else{
            $(button).html('<img src="'+site_url+'images/core/icons/basic2/star1_16_gray.png" />');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$("#"+element_id)` instead.  `$(this)` isn't working because you're not running this function as a method on an object.

Improving on the other answers, try this:

```
$(".save_button").click(function(){
toggle_save_star(element_id, site_url, $(this));
});
```

and in your function, the third new argument (called "`target`", let's say) could be used like this:

```
var button = target;
```

then use button like `button.html(...);`

Answer (score 4):

I think in this case "this" don't reference to the div. You should try:

```
$('.save_button').click(function(){
  $(this)...
});
```

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but wouldn't this force me to move the code inside all the relevant html pages? If not, how would I pass the two arguments if it was written this way?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that when you assign a string to onclick in your markup as in:

```
<div class="save_button" onclick="toggle_save_star..."
```

then, the code in the quotes gets evaluated by eval() and the `this` pointer will be set to point to the `window` object, not to the object that generated the click.  If you want `this` set appropriately, then you can't assign the onclick handler in the markup, you would need to do it with JS as in:

```
$(".save_button").click();
```

or some other way in code.

In addition, there's a coding error in your `toggle_save_star` function.

Your `button` variable is already a jQuery object so you don't need to try to make it into another one with `$(button)`.  If you were going to use that function, you would have to change it to this:

```
function toggle_save_star(element_id, site_url) {
    var url = site_url+"AJAX/ajax_default/modify_saved";
    var button = $(this);
    $.post(url,{action: 'toggle', element_id: element_id, type: 'listing' }, function(data) {
        if(data == 'saved') {
            button.html('<img src="'+site_url+'images/core/icons/basic2/star1_16.png" />');
        }
        else{
            button.html('<img src="'+site_url+'images/core/icons/basic2/star1_16_gray.png" />');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off removing the onclick from your div and going with something like the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/cpeele00/epD3v/

This allows you access the clickable item, in this case 'save_button'.

Then, at the bottom of your page (before you reach the closing body tag, insert your script there).

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

  //CALL THE FUNCTION HERE           


  //DEFINE THE FUNCTION HERE (see the jsFiddle link above)

  });

</script>
</body>
```